# run code on div below and not all divs with same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code is executing on all instances of .flow-hold and not just the div below the .title-hold with text that matches the ==.
The reason for this is I need to change the ranges that I use for each of the gauge1, gauge2, gauge3 instances. I have tried $('.flow-hold').next(function(){
but this is not working either......many thanx in advance

```js
$('.title-hold').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'gauge1') {
    $('.flow-hold').each(function() {
      if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 0.0 && ($(this).text()) <= 100.0) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "green");
      } else if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 101.0 && ($(this).text()) <= 200.0) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
      } else if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 300.0 && ($(this).text()) <= 400.0) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "red");
      } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "purple");
      }
    });
  } else {
    //do nothing
  }
});


$('.title-hold').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text() == 'gauge2') {
    $('.flow-hold').each(function() {
      if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 0.0 && ($(this).text()) <= 250.0) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "orange");
      } else if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 251.0 && ($(this).text()) <= 345.0) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "pink");
      } else if (parseInt($(this).text()) >= 346.0 && ($(this).text()) <= 800.0) {
        $(this).css("background-color", "brown");
      } else {
        $(this).css("background-color", "purple");
      }
    });

  } else {
    //do nothing
  }
});
```

```css
.title-hold {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.flow-hold {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title-hold">gauge1</div>
<div class="flow-hold">200</div>

<div class="title-hold">gauge2</div>
<div class="flow-hold">10.5</div>

<div class="title-hold">gauge3</div>
<div class="flow-hold">325.5</div>
```

Comment: you are trying to accessing the text of "flow-hold" and there are more than 1 so they are being called as an array all together and using element.querSelectorAll might help?

Comment: Just add a unique id to each and work with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for multiple loops. Just loop once and upon each loop iteration check all `gauge` values and act accordingly.

Also, it's simpler to work with CSS classes, rather than setting inline styles.

Additionally, be careful with your `>=` and `<=` values. The way you have it, if a value were `100.5`, it wouldn't match any condition. You may not be planning on working with decimal values right now, but by changing the range a bit, you are safeguarded for the future.

See comments inline.

```js
$('.title-hold').each(function() {
  let text = $(this).text();           // Get the text of the .title-hold element
  
  // Get a reference to the .flow-hold element that follows it.
  // .next() with no arguments will return the next sibline element after the current one.
  let next = $(this).next();
  
  // Get the text of the .flow-hold element that follows it and convert to a number.
  // The pre-pended "+" here forces a conversion of the string to a number.
  let num = +next.text();    
  
  // Depending on what the text of the current .title-hold element being looped is...
  switch(text){
    case 'gauge1':
      if(num >= 0 && num <= 100){
        next.addClass("green");        
      } else if(num <= 200){  // <-- NOTE: the previous test already handled values <=100 
        next.addClass("yellow");       
      } else if(num <= 400){
        next.addClass("red");       
      } else {
        next.addClass("purple");       
      } 
      break;
    case 'gauge2':
      if(num >= 0 && num <= 250){
        next.addClass("orange");        
      } else if(num <= 345){
        next.addClass("pink");       
      } else if(num <= 800){
        next.addClass("brown");       
      } else {
        next.addClass("purple");       
      }     
      break;
      
    case 'gauge3':
      // Repeat the if statement from above, but with appropriate tests and classes 
      break;
  }
});
```

```css
.title-hold {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.flow-hold {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
}


/* These classes will be conditionally applied */
.green { background-color:green; }
.yellow { background-color:yellow; }
.red { background-color:red; }
.purple { background-color:purple; }
.orange { background-color:orange; }
.pink { background-color:pink; }
.brown { background-color:brown; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title-hold">gauge1</div>
<div class="flow-hold">200</div>

<div class="title-hold">gauge2</div>
<div class="flow-hold">10.5</div>

<div class="title-hold">gauge3</div>
<div class="flow-hold">325.5</div>
```

Comment: How would the code need to be modified to work if there were 2 div tags between the title-hold and the flow hold? Would there be a way to skip the 2 new divs and then have the code run as it does now?

Comment: .next().next()  ?

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```js
const gaugeConfig = {
'gauge1': {
    ranges: [
        {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
            color: 'green'
        },
        {
            min: 101,
            max: 200,
            color: 'yellow'
        },
        {
            min: 300,
            max: 400,
            color: 'red'
        }
    ],
    defaultColor: 'purple'
},
'gauge2': {
    ranges: [
        {
            min: 0,
            max: 250,
            color: 'orange'
        },
        {
            min: 251,
            max: 345,
            color: 'pink'
        },
        {
            min: 346,
            max: 800,
            color: 'brown'
        }
    ],
    defaultColor: 'purple'
},
}

function updateColors(flowHold, config) {
flow = parseFloat(flowHold.text());
flowHold.css("background-color", config.defaultColor);
for( var i=0; i < config.ranges.length; i++ ) {
        range = config.ranges[i];
    if (flow >= range.min && flow <= range.max) {
        flowHold.css("background-color",range.color);
        break;
    }
}
}

$('.flow-hold').each(function() {
flowHold = $(this);
titleHold = flowHold.prev();
title = titleHold.text();
config = gaugeConfig[title];
if (config)
    updateColors(flowHold, config);
});
```

```css
.title-hold {
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
 font-size: 18px;
}

.flow-hold {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
 font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title-hold">gauge1</div>
<div class="flow-hold">200</div>

<div class="title-hold">gauge2</div>
<div class="flow-hold">10.5</div>

<div class="title-hold">gauge3</div>
<div class="flow-hold">325.5</div>

<div class="title-hold">gauge4</div>
<div class="flow-hold">201</div>
```

Comment: The color of the `flow-hold` element depends on whether the preceding `title-hold` is `gauge1` or `gauge2`.

Comment: Also, the value ranges for each color depend on that.

Answer (score 0):

`.next()` doesn't take a function argument, you just use it to get the element that you want to act on.

Also, the `else if` statements don't need to check the lower limits. The `<=` test in the preceding `if` ensures that the number is above that limit. Your code was also skipping values between `100.0` and `101.0` -- they would end up in the `else` at the end.

```js
$('.title-hold').each(function() {
  var flowHold = $(this).next('.flow-hold');
  var nextVal = parseInt(flowHold.text());
  if ($(this).text() == 'gauge1') {
    if (nextVal >= 0.0 && nextVal <= 100.0) {
      flowHold.css("background-color", "green");
    } else if (nextVal <= 200.0) {
      flowHold.css("background-color", "yellow");
    } else if (nextVal <= 400.0) {
      flowHold.css("background-color", "red");
    } else {
      flowHold.css("background-color", "purple");
    }
  } else if ($(this).text() == 'gauge2') {
    if (nextVal >= 0.0 && nextVal <= 250.0) {
      flowHold.css("background-color", "orange");
    } else if (nextVal <= 245.0) {
      flowHold.css("background-color", "pink");
    } else if (nextVal <= 800.0) {
      flowHold.css("background-color", "brown");
    } else {
      flowHold.css("background-color", "purple");
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.title-hold {
  width: 100%;
  background: #000;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.flow-hold {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="title-hold">gauge1</div>
<div class="flow-hold">200</div>

<div class="title-hold">gauge2</div>
<div class="flow-hold">10.5</div>

<div class="title-hold">gauge3</div>
<div class="flow-hold">325.5</div>
```

Comment: I think the colors are supposed to be applied to the `.flow-hold` elements, not the `.title-hold` elements.